# How can I make a custom JS function?

Tags: javascript, dry

Here is an idea of what I'm trying to do - a custom shorthand:

```js
on_cl('#id' /* or .class instead of #id */){
  // insert code here
}
```

, to not paste this over and over:

```js
document.querySelector('#id' /* or .class */).addEventListener('click', () => {
  // insert code here
})
```

. Basically, these 2 chunks of code should be equivalent.

How can I do this?

I searched for an answer on [MDNdocs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Building_blocks/Build_your_own_function), but didn't find what I wanted.

Comment: "I searched for an answer on MDNdocs, but didn't find what I wanted." — That is what you want. It hard to tell what problem you are having understanding it without seeing your attempt.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Functions

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want a shortcut for an already existing method, you will need to pass in the parameters of the new function everything you need to write in the original method. In your case you would need the selector and the callback of the event, so the function should look like this :

```
function on_cl(selector, eventCallback){
  document.querySelector(selector).addEventListener('click', eventCallback)
}
```

And call it like this :

```
on_cl('#id', () => {
  /// your callback
});
```

---

#### Edit

As David Thomas suggested in the comments, it is also possible to change the event to listen to.

In the function `on_cl`, the only event to listen to is "click". This can be changed by passing it as an argument of the function

```
function on_event(selector, eventType, eventCallback){
  document.querySelector(selector).addEventListener(eventType, eventCallback)
}

on_event('#id', 'click', () => {
  /// your callback
});
```

If you want, you can then create multiple shortcuts for each event you need to listen to, like this :

```
function on_click(selector, eventCallback){
  on_event(selector, "click", eventCallback);
}

function on_mouse_up(selector, eventCallback){
  on_event(selector, "mouseup", eventCallback);
}

// etc...
```

Comment: It might be worth showing how to - and explaining the benefits of - adding the event-type as an additional parameter for future extensibility, `on_cl(selector, EventType, eventCallback)`.

Comment: You are right, i added this information. Thank you !

Comment: No problem at all, thank you for taking the time to help :)

Comment: that ruins the whole idea of mine

Comment: What is the idea then ?

Comment: @danik0011: so update your question to explain your "idea," so far you've asked a terrible question with insufficient detail for anyone to realistically work out what you're trying to do, let alone trying to drive anything so vague as your "idea."

Comment: update a year later: this is actually pretty good